# Why my svm.SVC.fit( ) (linear kernal) run so long time?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I am using sklearn.svm.SVC( ) to train & test my dataset. 80% are used for training, 20% are used for testing.

Here is my Python code:

```
data = pd.read_csv(trainPath, header=0)

X = data.iloc[:, 5:17].values
y = data.iloc[:, 17:18].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

print(X_train.dtype, y_train.dtype)  # float64 int64

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
print('done')

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print("Accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Precision:", metrics.precision_score(y_test, y_pred))
print("Recall:", metrics.recall_score(y_test, y_pred))
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).ravel()
print(tn, fp, fn, tp)
```

For data.shape = 30,000 x 13, it runs around 15 mins.

For data.shape = 130,000 x 13, it runs more than 1 hour.

Why it runs so long time, I don't think it is normal.

- i5, 2.8GHz, 16.0 GB memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From scikit-learn documentation:

> The implementation is based on libsvm. **The fit time scales at least quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond tens of thousands of samples**. For large datasets consider using sklearn.linear_model.LinearSVC or sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier instead, possibly after a sklearn.kernel_approximation.Nystroem transformer.

Yo can change

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

by

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
clf = LinearSVC(random_state=0, tol=1e-5)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.ravel())
```

Comment: how about the speed of LinearSVC?

Comment: In the liblinear web page its reported that, for the same dataset, linearsvm gets 97% in  3 seconds whilst svm gets 96.8% in 346 seconds... 
 https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/